# Problems with custom MIPS toolchain and abicall stuff

Tags: gcc, mips, toolchain, uclibc, crosstool-ng

I'm working on a project focusing on the MIPS32 arch (little endian). The vendor gave me a GNU toolchain to compile my project targeting their embedded Linux version and everything works just fine. It's a GCC+Linux+uClibc toolchain.

However, recently I've needed to add some features to my uClibc build, so I've tried to replicate the vendor's toolchain in my own box.

Everything worked fine with the help of crosstool-ng, but when I try to compile my project, I get strange linker warnings all over the place:

```
warning: linking abicalls files with non-abicalls files
```

From what I researched, these are pretty serious warnings. Analyzing my object files with readelf will give me almost identical output. There are no .abicall section anywhere in those files. This holds true for both my project's object files to my toolchain's ones.

What could be wrong here? I don't even know where to start debugging this.

Comment: Did you try gcc `-mabicalls` option?

Comment: @MaratDukhan I don't want to because it works properly with the other toolchain. My object files are created with the -mno-abicalls option. I want to find out what is different in this new toolchain.

Comment: Probably some of the assembly sources contain `.abicalls` directive

Comment: But I've just tested it and the errors are the same. Looks like I just can't find what object the linker is complaining about. Everything seems to use the SYSV ABI.

Comment: @MaratDukhan No assembly sources contain .abicalls - must be some object file somewhere. I wonder why this stop working just by changing the toolchain!!